# Lerna / Webpack : How to retrieve a repository environment variable inside a submodule

Tags: node.js, api, vue.js, webpack, lerna

I'm working on a VueJS app (+ webpack + lerna) with the following code architecture :

- package.json
- lerna.json
- packages/
- modules/
- plugins/

All the submodules (modules + packages) make calls to a REST API.

So far the REST API URL is defined **during the build step** using webpack DefinePlugin, either directly inside the code, either with a cross-env command :

```
cross-env API_URL=http://www.the_api_url.com npm run bootstrap --hoist
```

I would like the REST API URL to be defined **when the server starts** (not during the build) using repository **environment variables** (process.env at the root of the repository).

> I tried having a .env file at the root, but it didn't manage to access
>   its data inside a module. The module seems to be only reading its own
>   .env file.

Do you have any solution or can you point me into the right direction to obtain the same result in another way ?